# Clickable fields on list view

Tags: 2010, list-view

I wonder if is possible to make a property of a view clickable.

For example if my list is like a list of docs (CT: Item) created with the attach file function via UI.

The view:

```
_____________________________________

|   ID  |   Name    |       File    |
-------------------------------------
|   01  |   t.txt   |   path\t.txt  |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to click on `path\t.txt` and open / download the file, let's assume that the path is accessible from / within sharepoint.

All this should be realized via code in VS, without SP designer.

Is it possible? What you suggest?

NB:For "via code in VS" I mean that the solution should be delivered by deploying or activating a feature, not for example, using Sharepoint Designer, that in my case is not a valid way.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information/details to be able to answer. Please clarify your exact scenario (one over all: what do you mean by "via code in VS", what have you done so far exactly?)

Comment: A dataview web part (DVWP) would be the easiest way to go, but that would require SPD, not VS. Are you building the list view dynamically using the SharePoint API?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You tagged your question with 2010 - unfortunately this solution will only work for SharePoint 2013. But I'll leave it here for the benefit of anyone searching for a 2013 solution.

-

You can achieve this with Client Side Rendering. You will need to point the page to a JavaScript file, which will look something like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", CSR_Setup);

function CSR_Setup() {
    var overridectx = {};
    overridectx.Templates = {};
    overridectx.Templates.Fields = {
        "File": { "View": CSR_AddFileLinks }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overridectx);
}

function CSR_AddFileLinks(ctx) {
    var filePath = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return String.format('<a href="{0}">{0}</a>', filePath);
}
```

Comment: He tagged his question with 2010, meaning that CSR is NOT an option!

Comment: He did indeed! I won't delete this answer for the benefit of anyone requiring a 2013 solution.